# Can you use RPM to distribute a *.bin file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I've never had to do this and I'm not really sure you can do it or not. But can I use RPM to distribute an already created *.bin file (a Linux self extracting binary files). My scenario is this, we use RPM to distribute all of our software. I have a piece of vendor software thats already a bin file. Say myapp.bin. I would like to use RPM to distribute the software to say /tmp and then kick off a script to install myapp.bin as part of the RPM %post%. Is this possible? If so, does anyone have a SPEC file example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not extract the self-extractor at build-time, then include the extracted, installed files in the RPM?

You can presumably do this with the scripts in the %build and %install sections.

Then nobody would need to worry about running the self-extractor, it would all be already there.

Comment: I could do that but this vendor product excepts a silent install file which allows you to customize installation directories, etc. so to keep it flexible we would only have to change the silent install file for future re-use. The problem appears to be that the binary is getting reduced in size when its getting built after I call rpmbuild.

Comment: rpmbuild may be stripping debug info off the binary - you can change this with some weird macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just extract the .bin file to the buildroot (%setup), execute it (in the %build section), and then do any modifications in the %install section.

Finally, just list the installed files in the %files section..if you post what you have for a spec I can probably adjust to enough to illustrate what I am saying if this is not clear.